# ssh-copy-id can not work with `~/.ssh/config`

Tags: ssh, authentication, ssh-tunnel, ssh-keys

I am able to login to a server using ssh `USER@HOST` without password, but password is required if I enter `ssh usdev` which is configured in `~/.ssh/config` like following:

```
Host usdev
    HostName HOST
    User USER
    IdentityFile /Users/USER/.ssh/id_rsa_us_east
```

This is the part of log file of ssh usdev:

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/USER/.ssh/id_rsa_us_east RSA SHA256:xgKp1AxWfSaujfWqlJe3G4kUioRbuICDDJ2645VVVAs explicit
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `ssh USER@HOST`, ssh uses default key.
When you `ssh usdev`, ssh uses the key specified in your `config` file. They must be different keys.
As far as I know, by default ssh uses `~/.ssh/id_rsa` as key. So I'm guessing that key is the real key to your `HOST`.